# JSON.NET cast error when serializing Mongo ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net

I am playing around with MongoDB and have an object with a mongodb ObjectId on it.
When I serialise this with the .NET Json() method, all is good (but the dates are horrible!)

If I try this with the JSON.NET serialiser it gives me an InvalidCastException when trying to serialise the ObjectID

any ideas whats happening and how I can fix this?

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//this is a route on a controller
   public string NiceJsonPlease()
    {

        var q = new TestClass();
        q.id = new ObjectId();
        q.test = "just updating this";

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(q);
    }

    //simple test class
    class TestClass
    {
        public ObjectId id; //MongoDB ObjectID
        public string test = "hi there";
    }


Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

If you change the controller method to use the serializer that ships with .NET, it works ok (but, this one gives ugly dates, blugh)

```
public JsonResult NiceJsonPlease()
    {

        var q = new TestClass();
        q.id = new ObjectId();
        q.test = "just updating this";

        return Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: ah, the old Json dates issue: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: @Liam hi Liam, I actually read that blog earlier today and is sort of the reason I am asking this question. JSON.NET gives me the nicer date but if I include the MongoDB ObjectID in my model and try and serialize it with JSON.NET, it errors.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I had similar problem when use atribute [BsonDefaultValue(0)] over property and use ProjectionDefinition to get data form MongoDB
[BsonDefaultValue(0)] 
public long SomePropery;

Solution is remove atribute.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had a pointer from the MongoDB user group.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-csharp/A_DXHuPscnQ

The response was

> This seems to be a Json.NET issue, but not really.  There is a custom
> type here it simply doesn't know about.  You need to tell Json.NET how
> to serialize an ObjectId.

So, I implemented the following solution

I decorated my ObjectId with

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
```

Then wrote a custom converter that just spits out the Guid portion of the ObjectId

```
 class ObjectIdConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { 
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
       
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ObjectId).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        //return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me. I found a completed version of a class with the same name here: https://github.com/geersch/MySinglePageApplication/blob/master/MvcApplication/Models/ObjectIdConverter.cs

Comment: @Syed Muhammed Mubashir,
To make this work, just add a conversion attribute above the ObjectId field.

[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
public ObjectId SiteUserId { get; set; }

Comment: Better way - register converter globally - _serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new ObjectIdConverter() }
            };

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction, I was experiencing issues in converting BsonDocument to JSON. Big thanks.

Comment: @DougJohnson - I tried above solution but i am getting error. I have posted question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446519/mongodb-objectid-conversion-error-in-c-sharp-using-newtonsoft-deserialization

Answer (score 66):

You can use .NET string type instead of ObjectId, You just need to decorate it with BsonRepresentation. If you use BsonDateTime, you will have the same conversion issue. This is a domain class in my project that uses those decorators.

```
public class DocumentMetadata
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime DownloadTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works effectively. Thanks for the Date inclusion.

Answer (score 23):

1. Write ObjectId converter

   public class ObjectIdConverter : JsonConverter
   {
   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
   {
   return objectType == typeof(ObjectId);
   }

   ```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String)
            throw new Exception($"Unexpected token parsing ObjectId. Expected String, got {reader.TokenType}.");

        var value = (string)reader.Value;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? ObjectId.Empty : new ObjectId(value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is ObjectId)
        {
            var objectId = (ObjectId)value;
            writer.WriteValue(objectId != ObjectId.Empty ? objectId.ToString() : string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Expected ObjectId value.");
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. Register it in JSON.NET globally with global settings and you not need mark you models with big attributes

   ```
            var _serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new ObjectIdConverter() }
            };
   ```
3. Big advice - don't use ObjectId in your models - use string

   [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
   public string Id{ get;set; }

Comment: Can you also please list which imports you used. I'm assuming: using System; using MongoDB.Bson; using Newtonsoft.Json;

Answer (score 10):

I resolved a similar problem I was experiencing with the JSON.NET serializer/InvalidCastException error by setting the JsonOutputMode to strict, which eradicated the need to change the underlying type:

```
var jsonWriterSettings = new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict };
var json = doc.ToJson(jsonWriterSettings);
```

With further information available in the API:  http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.8.3/html/d73bf108-d68c-e472-81af-36ac29ea08da.htm

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something like this. I was having trouble converting the JsonString because it contained invalid types.

Comment: Perfect answer, you should get a medal for this one. I was looking for it over 2 days.

Comment: you deserve a raise

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem with a Web API project, and wound up beating my head against the keyboard for a few hours before I found this thread.

Initially everything was working fine, but then I ran into the problem after converting my code to use my own custom class instead of the BsonDocument object as recommended in the mongoDB C# driver documentation.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#bsondocument-object-model-vs-your-own-domain-classes

Here the VB.net equivalent to the solution above for those that need it;

```
Public Class DocumentMetadata
    <BsonId> _
    <BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)> _
    Public Property Id() As String
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property FullName() As String

    <BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind := DateTimeKind.Utc)> _
    Public Property DownloadTime() As DateTime
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an another option

```
object dotnetObject = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(bsonDocument);

// Json mapped to default .Net objects
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dotnetObject);

// Parsing as JObject
var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

// Deserializing as your custom Type
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);
```

Comment: It worked for converting MongoDBRealm objects in Xamarin.iOS. Had to convert the RealmObject into a BsonDocument first.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in VB.Net and worked perfect, you can see the objectId in the class and you can do the same thing with the data type DATE.

```
    Imports MongoDB.Bson
    Imports MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes    
    Imports MongoDB.Driver

Public Class _default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim objMongo As New MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.111.5:27017")
        Dim objDatabase As IMongoDatabase = objMongo.GetDatabase("local")
        Dim objCollection = objDatabase.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Test")            
        Dim _ret As New List(Of mongo_users)

        Dim result = objCollection.Find(New BsonDocument()).ToList()
        Dim _json_response = result.ToJson()
        If _json_response <> "" Then

            _ret = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of mongo_users))(_json_response)

        End If

        For Each item In _ret
            Response.Write(item.name & " " & item.last_name & "</br>")
        Next


    End Sub

End Class

Public Class mongo_users            
    <BsonId>
    <BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)>
    Public Property _id() As String
    Public Property status As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property last_name As String
    Public Property colors As List(Of user_colors)    
End Class

Public Class user_colors
    Public Property color_name As String
End Class
```