# MongoDB C# driver and MVC4 webapi. Issue in json serialization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB database with MVC4 WebAPI using the C# driver provided by MongoDB. I have a an issue with serialization. I get the following error,

```
    "ExceptionMessage=Error getting value from '__emptyInstance' on 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'"
```

If I change the Content-Type to xml in my HTTP request it just works fine. I would appreciate any help.

I have copied the model below.

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public ObjectId _id;

    public long SubscriberId { get; set; }

    public Name Name { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Subscription> Subscription { get; set; }


    public Subscriber()
    {
        Name = new Name();
        Address = new Address();
        Subscription = new Collection<Subscription>();
}
}
```

**Solution**

Converting _id type string and decorating the field as below did the trick

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string _id;
```

reference: [JSON.NET cast error when serializing Mongo ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651776/json-net-cast-error-when-serializing-mongo-objectid)

Comment: Could you share how your type that you are trying to serialize into JSON looks like? Also, from the error it says `MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId`, is it supposed to be a Bson formatter instead? Filip has an example of creating a BSON formatter here: https://gist.github.com/filipw/3160050

Comment: could you share your model

Comment: I have copied the model above. The issue is that the ObjectId is not getting serialized. Thx

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying the mentioned "solution" in the answer : It simply doesn't work!

Check the marked answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651776/json-net-cast-error-when-serializing-mongo-objectid),  instead.