# Globally use a JsonConverter on a class without the attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, json.net

I have a MVC .net project, and I am using mongodb. 
I use a custom JsonConverter to serialize ObjectId properties as a string, as I describes in this answer:
[Automatically retun mongodb ObjectId as string with Json.NET in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27316211/3142584)

In there I used an attribue so that the custom converter is used on a certain property: `[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))`

Is there a way to tell the serializer to use the ObjectIdConverter on all properties of type ObjectId?
I don't wan't to go over on the entire project and add this property.

Thanks!

Comment: try BsonSerializer.RegisterIdGenerator(typeof(xxx), new XXXObjectIdGenerator());

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom `IContractResolver` to programmatically apply a `JsonConverter` to a class or property.  The simplest way to do this is to derive your resolver from the `DefaultContractResolver` class and then override the appropriate method.  Below is an example resolver that instructs Json.Net to use an `ObjectIdConverter` on all instances of the `ObjectId` type, regardless of what class they might appear in.

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (objectType == typeof(ObjectId))
        {
            contract.Converter = new ObjectIdConverter();
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

To use the resolver, you can construct a `JsonSerializer` instance and set the `ContractResolver` property on it, then use that instance to do your serialization/deserialization.  If you are using  `JObject.ToObject()` and `JObject.FromObject()`, note that both methods have overloads that accept a `JsonSerializer` instance.

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();

JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(foo, serializer);
```

Alternatively, if you are using the `JsonConvert` class to do your serialization/deserialization,  you can create an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings`, set the `ContractResolver` property on that, then pass the settings to the `SerializeObject()` and `DeserializeObject()` methods.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();

Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, settings);
```

Hope this helps.