# Automatically apply JsonConverter attribute to all properties of type

Tags: c#, json.net, converters

**I have a custom JsonConverter** for `DateTimeOffset` properties in my ViewModels. I have 100+ ViewModels.

```
public class ItemViewModel 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeOffsetConverter))]
  public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

How can I apply this attribute to all DateTimeOffset properties, without adding it to all my ViewModels?

I thought I had the solution when I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333955/433384), but when I apply it, the CustomResolver only fires on the parent object itself, and not the DateTimeOffset property, or any property.

```
public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
        {
            contract.Converter = new CustomDateTimeOffsetConverter();
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

So to recap, I have everything else working. If I add the `[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeOffsetConverter))]` attribute manually, then my application works like a charm. I am only asking how to add the attribute automatically, instead of manually.

Comment: if you mean without applying the attribute you want to serialize the object?? use the `Newtonsoft.json` install this package from `NuGet`

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the converter to the `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` passed to the serializer.

Your `JsonSerializerSettings` will look as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    Converters =
            {
                new CustomDateTimeOffsetConverter()
            }
};
```

Your custom converter should also advertise it can convert the `DateTimeOffset` type with the following override of the `JsonConverter` method:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return (objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset));
}
```

Comment: To set the converter globally, see [How to tell Json.Net globally to apply the StringEnumConverter to all enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427909/how-to-tell-json-net-globally-to-apply-the-stringenumconverter-to-all-enums).