# Is there a way to pass JsonSerializerSettings to JsonPatchDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-patch

Looks like, JsonPatchDocument's ApplyTo takes the serialization settings from JsonConvert.DefaultSettings. There should be a way to pass custome JsonSerializerSettings to th library so ApplyTo can user specific settings such as customized JsonConverters.

Is there a way to do so?

CurrentSolution:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => JsonSerializerSettings;
patchDoc.ApplyTo(obj);
```

Ideally I shouldn't need to override the global serializer settings. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Can you please add a [mre] showing actual problem/sample json/desired output?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you need to do?  There is a [`JsonPatchDocument(List<Operation>, IContractResolver)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch.jsonpatchdocument.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-jsonpatch-jsonpatchdocument-ctor(system-collections-generic-list((microsoft-aspnetcore-jsonpatch-operations-operation))-newtonsoft-json-serialization-icontractresolver)) constructor that allows you to pass in a contract resolver.  Maybe that will be sufficient to meet your needs.

Comment: E.g. contract resolvers do let you apply converters, see e.g. [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333955) by Brian Rogers to [Globally use a JsonConverter on a class without the attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27332258).  And see Brian's answer to [JSON.net ContractResolver vs. JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088492) for a breakdown of what you might be able to do with a custom contract resolver.

Comment: Actually, for this kind of scenario  couple of ways to acheive what you are expecting. However, it would be great if you could share more details about your implementation.