# Returning ObjectID as a string from ASP.NET Core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, objectid

How to you get a string representation of the `ObjectId` returned via ASP.NET Core.

I have the following result of an action in my controller:

```
return new ObjectResult(new { session, user });
```

One of the user properties is the `UserId` that is of the `ObjectId` type.

However, this gets returned in the response as

```
"id": {
  "timestamp": 1482840000,
  "machine": 6645569,
  "pid": 19448,
  "increment": 5052063,
  "creationTime": "2016-12-27T12:00:00Z"
}
```

I would like the response to simply be `58625d5201c4f202609fc5f3` that is the string representation of the same structure.

Are there any easy way to do this for all returned `ObjectIds`?

**EDIT** 
Adding some more data

Here are the user class. `ObjectId` is `MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId`

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

The get method in my controller. `Controller` is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`.

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetUser")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ObjectId id)
{
    var user = await _repository.GetOne<User>(id);
    if (user == null) return NotFound();
    return new ObjectResult(user);
}
```

And this is the method from my repository:

```
public async Task<T> GetOne<T>(ObjectId id)
{
    var collectionname = typeof(T).Name;
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<T>(collectionname);
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
    var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: ObjectId should be serialised to string by default

Comment: It's not apparently. I have not set up anything special here, but this is what I get back from the service.

Comment: try doing .ToString() on the Id property explicitly. As far as I know .NET Core internally uses JSON.net which should have taken care of it. Can you share your Document, Repository & Service code.

Comment: I added some more information to my post now. However manual ToString is not a solution for me, since it's part of the object returned, and this problem is the same for all objects having a objectid, and I don't want to add random ToString calls all over the place .

Comment: You dont use BSON library ?? I mean thats the json parser for mongo db which handles the serilization of objectId internally. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/?jmp=docs&_ga=1.157787902.532881143.1480104239

Comment: @SagarReddy. Not sure which library you are referring to here. I use the MongoDB.Bson library that are part of the official MongoDB driver for windows, but no other library specific to mongodb/bson in ASP.NET.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37966098/887976

Comment: Can you try using `public string Id { get; set; }` ? The serailizer should take care of converting it to ObjectId for you. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#objectids

Comment: Agreed with @SagarReddy. At least thats how I recall doing it in the past. Don't forget to stick the attribute on the property.

Comment: I really don't want to make the Id a string (since it is an ObjectId), and I don't want to stick attributes to the fields either. But the link provided by @ChirdeepTomar helped a lot. I created a new JsonConverter for ObjectId like the one in that post, and configured it inside ConfigureServices -> AddJsonOptions and it worked as I wanted it to. And I wont have to put the attributes around all my models :D

Comment: Thanks for helping me out guys. @ChirdeepTomar, if you make it a proper answer instead of a comment, I'll give you an upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly write a ObjectID to JSON convertor. Please check the link below: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37966098/887976

Comment: Note that to register this in ASP.NET Core you will have to add the following in your ConfigureServices method: `services.AddJsonOptions(opt =>  {opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ObjectIdConverter());});`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the string representation of an objectId, try changing the type of the field to use string first like so

```cs
// [BsonId] // use if primary key is not Id
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string? Id { get; set; }
```